# Distribute subscribers across JVMs

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, distributed-system

Per my understanding RXJava works within a single JVM. Is there a wrapper/lib/api to support clustered environments with combination of distributed cache, JMS or any other queue to provide subscribers scale across distributed environments?  Would like to check here before reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There exist adapters to various technologies, but maybe you should check out Spring 5 which has more comprehensible and integrated solutions for your use cases. They are reactive based as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy [Vertx](http://vertx.io) instances in a cluster and use RxJava over it. The idea is use [EventBus](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus) as a transport layer and subscribe to the messages using RxJava. It's not a pure RxJava solution.

A very simple runnable example:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.spi.cluster.ClusterManager;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.spi.cluster.hazelcast.HazelcastClusterManager;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    String nodeId;
    static final String CENTRAL = "CENTRAL";

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

        JsonObject config = config();
        String nodeID = config.getString("nodeID");

        eventBus.consumer(CENTRAL).toFlowable()
            .map(msg -> (JsonObject) msg.body())
            .filter(msgBody -> !msgBody.getString("sender", "").equals(nodeID))
            .subscribe(msgBody -> {
                System.out.println(msgBody);
            });

        Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(tick -> {
                JsonObject msg = new JsonObject()
                        .put("sender", nodeID)
                        .put("msg", "Hello world");
                eventBus.publish(CENTRAL, msg);
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClusterManager clusterManager = new HazelcastClusterManager();

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(clusterManager);

        Vertx.rxClusteredVertx(options)
            .doOnError(throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace())
            .subscribe(vertx -> {
                if (vertx.isClustered()) {
                    System.out.println("Vertx is running clustered");
                }
                String nodeID = clusterManager.getNodeID();
                System.out.println("Node ID : " + nodeID);

                String mainVerticle = MainVerticle.class.getCanonicalName();

                DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions();
                    deploymentOptions.setConfig(new JsonObject().put("nodeID", nodeID));

                vertx.rxDeployVerticle(mainVerticle, deploymentOptions).subscribe();
            });

    }

}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava2-clustered</artifactId>
    <version>0.42</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rxjava2-clustered</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In this example, I am  using Hazelcast ClusterManager. There exists implementations for Infinispan, Apache Ignite and Apache Zookeeper. Refer to [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/#clustering) for full reference:

Comment: I was looking exactly similar to this , i cant go with clustermanger defined here but i should able to investigate with redis vertix  as Event Bus. thanks for the links